# Trimming URLs with Regex?

Tags: regex

I'm using Notepad++ and I want to trim these kind of URLs:

```
12.12.abc-123.com
12.abc-123.com
123.123.abc-123.com
123.abc-123.com
a-.a-.abc-123.co.uk
a-.abc-123.co.uk
a-1.a-1.abc-123.co.uk
a-1.abc-123.co.uk
ab.ab.abc-123.mobi
ab.abc-123.mobi
abc.abc.abc-123.mobi
abc.abc-123.mobi
```

To look like this:

```
abc-123.com
abc-123.co.uk
abc-123.mobi
```

Any help?

Comment: Does the url contain only `.co.uk`, `.com` and `.mobi` top levels?

Comment: [`[^.]+\.(?:com|co\.uk|mobi)$`](https://regex101.com/r/xB9vQ8/1)

Comment: Seeing that notepad++ supports a multitude of scripting languages (and thus regex implementations) what language are you using?  It may affect what you end up having to use...

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
^.*?\.([^.]+\.(com|co\.uk|mobi))$
```

to:

```
\1
```

**Update**:

Let's assume that all TLDs that you have is either don't have a `.` in it or it has the pattern of `co.*`.

This will give you the following search pattern:

```
^.*?\.([^.]+(\.co)?\.[^.]+)$
```

Comment: Looks good here: https://regex101.com/r/vP9vA6/1 and tried it actually in Notepad++ as well. What actual line gets replaced wrongly?

Answer (score 0):

```
.*\.(?=.*-)
```

Try this.Replace by `empty string`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vN3sH3/62